# ABCpdfCE7.dll locked by IIS

Tags: .net, unmanaged, abcpdf

I have a website in ASP.Net that generates PDF with a 3rd party application called ABCPdf. ABCPdf consists of two dll : ABCpdf.dll and ABCpdfCE7.dll. ABCpdf.dll is a .NET wrapper for the unmanaged ABCpdfCE7.dll.

As soon as a pdf is generated. the ABCpdfCE7.dll is locked by IIS (i.e. cannot rename it or delete it) uneless I recycle the application pool or restart IIS. This cause problem when updating my website because we cannot overwrite ABCpdfCE7.dll.

Is there anyway to release the resource that is locking ABCpdfCE7.dll in .Net ? Restarting IIS or recycle the application pool at each update is not a solution because I have multiple websites running on it.

I'm disposing the object from the PDF library everytime

```
Using theDoc As New Doc

    // Generate the pdf

    theDoc.Clear()
End Using
```

Comment: Can you post your code where you use the PDF library?

Comment: Use a separate `AppPool` for each site, anyway- as this is just one of the array of possible problems you're going to encounter in the long term.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment I will check this solution, thank you

Comment: No worries, hope all goes well. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How often does ABCpdfCE7.dll change? I imagine not too often, so why are you pushing it with each update, just leave it out.

Plus, just a couple more observations:

Recycling the App Pool preserves sessions, so it shouldn't have any impact on your users, other than performance if your are caching a lot of expensive resources, and someone will get a first-hit delay.

ABCPdf, depending on how you're using it, spawns an instance of Internet Explorer to render HTML to PDF. You might check the the task manager to see if IE is running in the background, and if so, killing it could solve your problems, although I don't know how you would avoid possibly killing someone's PDF job.

Comment: Yes, not pushing the dll was a solution. I was looking for something else in case we forget to push it when we will update ABCpdf. Also, reclycling the application pool do not preserves the sessions on other website that are running on the same application pool

Comment: @Alexandre: Just to reiterate: give sites their own `AppPool`, period.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Couldn't using additional App Pools use up a lot more memory?

Comment: At the minute you're sharing memory, and worker processes - an `AppPool` can have a fixed amount of memory, which is even worse in this case. The application will use the memory it needs, compromised  by the memory available, which could result in automatic restarts of an application pool anyway. Memory is the least of your worries here.